# Getting user input after stdin has been redirected, in a bourne script

Tags: shell, sh

(this is indirectly a part of a much larger homework assignment)

I have something like

```
    while read LINE
    do
        stuff-done-to-$LINE
        echo "Enter input:"
        read INPUT
        stuff-done-to-$INPUT
    done < infile
```

I can't find a successful way of using the console/default stdin for the second read, instead of the redirected stdin.

Needs to be pure bourne script.

Comment: I should elaborate on the first bit... the question/problem is specific to my solution to the assignment, and isn't part of the homework assignment, but the requirement that my code is in non-extended Bourne is.

Comment: pure bourne script? You mean the original bourne shell, not bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is supported in the Bourne shell:

```
exec 3<doc.txt
while read LINE <&3
do
    stuff-done-to-$LINE
    # the next two lines could be replaced by: read -p "Enter input: " INPUT
    echo "Enter input:"
    read INPUT
    stuff-done-to-$INPUT
done < infile
```

Input is alternated between the file and the user. In fact, this would be a neat way to issue a series of prompts from a file.

This redirects the file "infile" to the file descriptor number 3 from which the first `read` gets its input. File descriptor 0 is `stdin`, 1 is `stdout` and 2 is `stderr`. You can use other FDs along with them.

I've tested this on Bash and Dash (on my system sh is symlinked to dash).

*Of course it works.* Here's some more fun:

```
exec 3<doc1.txt
exec 4<doc2.txt
while read line1 <&3 && read line2 <&4
do
    echo "ONE: $line1"
    echo "TWO: $line2"
    line1=($line1) # convert to an array
    line2=($line2)
    echo "Colors: ${line1[0]} and ${line2[0]}"
done
```

This alternates printing the contents of two files, discarding the extra lines of whichever file is longer.

```
ONE: Red first line of doc1
TWO: Blue first line of doc2
Colors: Red and Blue
ONE: Green second line of doc1
TWO: Yellow second line of doc2
Colors: Green and Yellow
```

Doc1 only has two lines. The third line and subsequent lines of doc2 are discarded.

Comment: Project and question is long gone, but I went back and checked the relevant shell... yes, it did support file descriptors, so your first example should have worked.
The second example with the arrays fails... no arrays in original bourne shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can read/write the user's terminal through /dev/tty, this is independent of what shell you are using and whether stdin/stdout are redirected, so you just need:

```
echo "Enter input:" > /dev/tty
read INPUT < /dev/tty
```

Answer (score 1):

This should to work:

```
for LINE in `cat infile`; do
   stuff-done-to-$LINE
   echo "Enter input:"
   read INPUT
   stuff-done-to-$INPUT
done
```

Comment: +1: yes and no. That will give you a list of words, not a list of lines. You have to change IFS to plain enter for your method to work, which can have dire consequences on the internal code if you are not careful and/or restore it.

Answer (score -2):

You can't. There's no default stdin and redirected stdin. There is stdin, and what it is connected to is either the console, or the file.

The only thing you can do is to do a while using a counter on the number of lines of your file. Then, extract each line using some smart use of sed or tail+head. You cannot use `while read line` because you would not have any way of differentiating the read from console and the read from the file.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of such. I can probably rewrite it differently, though tail+head is a bit nasty if the file is really big, and sed isn't much better.

Comment: Yes you can - see my answer on /dev/tty.