# how can I script a file as stdin to an app and then use the real stdin for user input?

Tags: bash, stdin

I have a closed source application that requires the "y" key be pressed after it has loaded to start working.
I need to automate this in such a way as that after the "y" character has been accepted 'normal' user input is accepted.

```
application < echo "y"
```

leaves the application with no access to user input

I guess I need a script that emulates

```
echo "y"
```

and then routes user input i.e. /dev/tty

part of the answer maybe in this SO question but how can I adapt it to an existing application?

[getting-user-input-after-stdin-has-been-redirected-in-a-bourne-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385380/getting-user-input-after-stdin-has-been-redirected-in-a-bourne-script)

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you really need is a tool to let you automate the pressing of the `y` key and, after that, enter in interactive mode. Please have a look at [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) for an example of such a tool.

Answer (score 3):

To flesh out jcollado's suggestion:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn application -with -options
expect "prompt where you have to enter y"
send -- "y\r"    # the "\r" represents the user "hitting enter"
interact
```

Comment: I need to investigate this further as this is for a GUI app running in X launched from a bash script. I will update when I have tried your solution.

Comment: @rob, `expect` cannot control GUI apps. You might have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: it seemed so logical, 
run script
script execute app, which happens to be GUI
normal stdin stdout.
how wrong could I be,
I ended up using xdotool which will find X windows by name and send key presses.
is it worth marking this question for deletion ?